# Matrix for recurrence relation

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, exponentiation

I have recurrence relation for which i need to figure out matrix which can used for matrix exponentiation.

$f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-3)$

Which I think can be written as
$f(n) = a f(n-1) + b f(n-2) + c f(n-3)$
where values of $a = 1, b = 0, c = 1$

```
| a  b  c |   | f(n-1) |   | f(n) |
| 1  0  0 | x | f(n-2) | = | f(n-1) |
| 0  1  0 |   | f(n-3) |   | f(n-2) |
```

By following this logic my matrix becomes

```
| 1  0  1 |
| 1  0  0 |
| 0  1  0 |
```

which I believe I can use for matrix exponentiation. However, it results in the wrong solution during matrix exponentiation.

But I can use the same matrix for generating series linearly.

```
    | 1  0  1 |   | f(n-1) |   | f(n) |
    | 1  0  0 | x | f(n-2) | = | f(n-1) |
    | 0  1  0 |   | f(n-3) |   | f(n-2) |

    | 1  0  1 |   | f(n) |     | f(n+1) |
    | 1  0  0 | x | f(n-1) | = | f(n) |
    | 0  1  0 |   | f(n-2) |   | f(n-1) |
```

Can someone please help me to know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be your matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\\1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Starting with given values $f(0),f(1),f(2)$, we can find any $f(n)$ for $n \geq 3$ using matrix exponentiation, i.e. denoting 
$$x_n = \begin{bmatrix} f(n) &  f(n-1) & f(n-2) \end{bmatrix}$$
we have
$$x_n = Ax_{n-1}=A^2x_{n-2} = \ldots =A^{n-2}x_2$$
Written differently,
$$\begin{bmatrix} f(n) \\  f(n-1) \\ f(n-2) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\\1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{n-2}\begin{bmatrix} f(2) \\  f(1) \\ f(0) \end{bmatrix} $$
which means you can generate any window of size three of $f$, given $a,b,c,f(2),f(1),f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks, i missed out last multiplication with initial set of matrix [fn, fn-1, fn-2]